# how to make a complicated output of a neural network keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I would like to combine 2 neural networks which are showing probabilities of classes. 
One says that it is a cat on the image.
The second says that the cat has a collar.

How to use softmax activation function on the output of the neural network?

Please, see the picture to understand the main idea:

[image: Network]

Comment: Can you provide minimal snippets of code, what you are trying to achieve etc? It's unclear.

Comment: I uploaded an image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) to create a multi-output network. Essentially every output will be a separate prediction. Something along the lines of:

```
in = Input(shape=(w,h,c)) # image input
latent = Conv...(...)(in) # some convolutional layers to extract features
# How share the underlying features to predict
animal = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(latent)
collar = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(latent)
model = Model(in, [animal, coller])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimiser='adam')
```

You can have as many separate outputs you like. If you have only binary features you can have a single vector output as well, `Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')` and first entry could predict cat or not, while second whether it has a collar. This would be multi-class multi-label setup.

Answer (score 1):

Juste create two separate dense layers (with sofmax activation) at the end of your model, e.g.:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model

# Input example:
inputs = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))

# Example of model:
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
# ... (replace with your actual layers)

# Then add two separate layers taking the previous output and generating two estimations:
cat_predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
collar_predictions = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[cat_predictions, collar_predictions])
```